# Printing 100 to 1 ?How?

Tags: c#

print 10 number on each line , Below Is The Code Of What I Did But Still Not Successful , Help

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i;

            for (i =100; i>=1; i--)
            {
                       Console.Write(i);

            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Loop For iterating 100 to 1.
Using that current Check for Index %10 == 0 Then , change the Console.Write to Console.Writeline(). Dont Copy Syntax , Understand it.

Comment: Why do you set i to 100 and then assign i the value 0?

Comment: @ThomasLindvall i finish the before code but how can i print 10 number on each line?

Comment: Did my answer get you what you are looking for? If yes, feel free to accept the answer so that it could help others in future to find the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for (i = 100; i >=1; i--)
{
    if(i%10==0)                 //if 10 numbers are printed
        Console.WriteLine();    //then line break
    Console.Write(i+" ");       //print the number with a space character
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

It will print 10 number in each line.

Result:

```
100 99 98 97 96 95 94 93 92 91 

90 89 88 87 86 85 84 83 82 81 

80 79 78 77 76 75 74 73 72 71 

70 69 68 67 66 65 64 63 62 61 

60 59 58 57 56 55 54 53 52 51 

50 49 48 47 46 45 44 43 42 41 

40 39 38 37 36 35 34 33 32 31 

30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 

20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 

10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

See result in [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/hQZ6j3).

Comment: What's that? How is your answer better than others?

Comment: OP wants to print 10 numbers on a line.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
       {
            int i=100;

             for (i; i <=100; i--)
             {
                Console.Write(i);
                 if(i==0)
                  {
                   break;
                  }

               }
             Console.ReadLine();   

        }
```

### Edit

Must use

```
if(i==0){break;}
```

otherwise this for loop does not end.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i;

            for (i = 100; i > 0; i--)
            {
                if(i%10==0)Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write(i);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Updated Demo:http://ideone.com/st4i8n

Comment: You are only answering part of the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 100; i >0; i--)
    {
        if (i % 10 == 0)
            Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write(i);                  
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might do what you need:

```
  Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Reverse()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(i => Console.Write(i % 10 == 1 ? i + "\r\n" : i + ", "));
```

Which will output:

```
100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91
90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83, 82, 81
80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71
70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61
60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51
50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41
40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31
30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21
20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11
10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Reverse().ToList().ForEach(n =>
    {
        Enumerable.Range(n * 10, 10).Select(i => i + 1).Reverse().ToList().ForEach(i => Console.Write(i + " "));
        Console.WriteLine();
    });

// output: 100 99 98 97 96 95 94 93 92 91
//         90 89 88 87 86 85 84 83 82 81
//         80 79 78 77 76 75 74 73 72 71
//         70 69 68 67 66 65 64 63 62 61
//         60 59 58 57 56 55 54 53 52 51
//         50 49 48 47 46 45 44 43 42 41
//         40 39 38 37 36 35 34 33 32 31
//         30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21
//         20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11
//         10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HundredToOne()
{
    for(int i=100;i>0;i--)
    {       
     if(i%10 == 0)
      Console.WriteLine("\n");

      Console.Write(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `StringBuilder` to build the 10 numbers per line, but concatenating like so should yield sufficient results (since it's only 100 numbers)

```
foreach (var number in Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray().Reverse())
{
    Console.Write((number % 10 == 0) ? "\n" : (number.ToString() + " "));
}
```